# How to have more control over screenshot name when using Firebase ScreenShotter in Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I have a helper class to generate screenshots when using Espresso. Screenshots are generated by using [Firebase ScreenShotter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/test-screenshots). My code is as follows:

```
    private static   ActivityScenario activityScenario;

    public static void setup(){
        activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class);
       
    }
    public static void screenshot(String name){
        activityScenario.onActivity(activity->{
            ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot(name, activity /* activity */);

        });
    }
```

So another class would call it like this:

```
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        SetupHelper.setup();
       
    }



    @Test
    public void loginAfterReset() {
         SetupHelper.screenshot("Home");
    }
```

The screenshots do save to the SD card of the device. However, the name of the screenshot on the SD card is:

```
UnknownTestClass-unknownTestMethod-Home-1.jpg
```

Why does it come up as UnknowntestClass-unknownTestMethod? How do I have more control over the naming?

Answer (score 2):

`ScreenShotter` uses the stack trace to figure out the filename, based on the test class and test method that it can find in the stack trace.

`ActivityScenario.onActivity()` runs the passed action on the current Activity's main thread. Tests are executed on a different thread. So, the action that you pass will have a Stack trace that doesn't include the test method or test class in it. That's the reason why you see `UnknownTestClass-unknownTestMethod`. When the anonymous function is executed, it's not running "in the context" of the test class.

One way to fix this is not using `onActivity()`. `ActivityScenario.launch()` should already bring your Activity into the "resumed" state, i.e. make it visible. Change your `SetupHelper.screenshot()` to the following:

```
    public static void screenshot(String name){
        ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot(name, activity /* activity */);
    }
```

This will change the screenshot filename to include the actual test class and test method name.